# pySQLite integration to pyGtk treeview

Tags: python, sqlite, gtk

Is there some simple way or how to integrate sqlite database into gtk.TreeModel (TreeView)?

What I want is to display data from a db in treeview, and it would be nice when I change something  in db to see the change in treeview and the other way round.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you put all your data in itemlist:

```
cur.execute('''select * from warehouse''')
itemlist = cur.fetchall()
```

To get list of column properties, do:

```
cur.execute('''PRAGMA table_info(warehouse)''')
```

To get only names of columns, you can then do:

```
colnames = [ i[1] for i in cur.fetchall() ]
```

Later you may need to set types in a ListStore for your TreeView, so do something like:

```
coltypes = [ i[2] for i in cur.fetchall() ]
for index, item in enumerate(coltypes):
    if (item == 'char'):
        coltypes[index] = str
    elif (item == 'integer'):
        coltypes[index] = int
```

Then put all info from your database to a TreeView:

```
store = gtk.ListStore(*coltypes)
for act in itemlist:
    store.append(act)
```

Now create columns for the TreeView (let's say it's called 'tree'):

```
for index, item in enumerate(colnames):
rendererText = gtk.CellRendererText()
column = gtk.TreeViewColumn(item, rendererText, text=index)
column.set_sort_column_id(index)
tree.append_column(column)
```

After that you should have automatically generated TreeView widget with correct columns and all the data. Source: [Advanced widgets in PyGTK](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pygtktutorial/advancedwidgets/)